# Higher order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I transform following DE using $t=x+e^x%$ as a substitution?

DE: $$(1+e^x)y'' - (1+3e^x+e^{2x})y'=(1+e^x)^3(x+e^x+e^xe^{e^x}$$

into $$y'' -y'=t+e^t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have  parametric functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, you have (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative)) $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}}$$ $$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac {dx}{dt}\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac {dy}{dt}\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}}{\left(\frac {dx}{dt}\right)^3}$$

In your case $$t=x+e^x\implies x=t-W\left(e^t\right)$$ where $W(t)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). So $$x=t-W\left(e^t\right)\implies\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{W\left(e^t\right)+1}\implies\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{W\left(e^t\right)}{\left(W\left(e^t\right)+1\right)^3}$$

Now, replacing in

$$(1+e^x)\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} - (1+3e^x+e^{2x})\frac {dy}{dx}-(1+e^x)^3(x+e^x+e^xe^{e^x})=0$$ after simplifications, taking into account the properties of Lambert function $$x=t-W\left(e^t\right)\implies e^x=W\left(e^t\right)\implies e^{2x}=W\left(e^t\right)^2\implies e^{e^x}=e^{W\left(e^t\right)}$$ we arrive at $$\left(\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac {dy}{dt}-t-e^t\right)\left(W\left(e^t\right)+1\right)^3=0$$ which reduces to $$\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac {dy}{dt}=t+e^t$$ as desired.